# Cannot parse E MMM dd yyyy date

Tags: java, datetime

I have the following code:

```
public static String convert( final String date )
{
    final DateTimeFormatterBuilder dateTimeFormatterBuilder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendOptional( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-yyyy" ) )
        .appendOptional( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy" ) )
        .appendOptional( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "E MMM dd yyyy" ) )
        .parseDefaulting( ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0 )
        .parseDefaulting( ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0 )
        .parseDefaulting( ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0 );

    final LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse( date, dateTimeFormatterBuilder.toFormatter() );

    return dateTime.format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-yyyy" ) );
}
```

But when the date is the following: Tue Apr 19 2022

It fails to convert but it shouldn't since the "E MMM dd yyyy" is there.

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Tue Apr 19 2022' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 0
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting `EEE` instead of `E` in the format string?

Comment: Check your locale settings.

Comment: @juzraai makes no difference.

Comment: @kylie.zoltan I doubt that. It fails for me as well, but if I call `toFormatter(Locale.ROOT)` instead of `toFormatter()`, then it works for me.

Comment: Specify your locale explicitly with a call to `withLocale`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Specify `Locale`

Specify a locale, to determine a human language and culture to use in translation.

```
final DateTimeFormatterBuilder dateTimeFormatterBuilder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendOptional( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-yyyy" ) )
    .appendOptional( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy" ) )
    .appendOptional( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "E MMM dd yyyy" ) )
    .parseDefaulting( ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0 )
    .parseDefaulting( ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0 )
    .parseDefaulting( ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0 );

String input = "Tue Apr 19 2022" ;
Locale locale = Locale.US ;
final LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , dateTimeFormatterBuilder.toFormatter().withLocale( locale ) );
System.out.println ( ldt ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/gb7qoD).

> 2022-04-19T00:00